# sort custom encoded data in mysql

Tags: mysql

i need to sort my data with one of my column in table which is **vendor_params**; the thing is it is an custom encoded data, below i have mentioned how i saved data in db
`vendor_min_pov="200"|vendor_min_poq=1`

firstly i was thinking to sort it through php but it was increasing the page load time, as some time query returns large data in an object of different keys of the same array and there are other filtration applying on that array too; so its good to sort that out via sql query.

i tried to search how can i order encoded data; but the solutions i got mostly is for serialize data; 
please help if some one can guide me how can i order the result of this table with the data values of **vendor_min_pov** in the column  **vendor_params**

Comment: Why don't you normalize your data? The example you showed looks as if it should be two columns named vendor_min_pov and vendor_min_poq.

Comment: You can use MySQL string functions like `INSTR()`, `LEFT()` and `MID()` to extract the data you want to sort on, but this is needlessly complex. You should use two columns to store this data.

Comment: @unique2 i can't actually this is only two value  written; this column is for param and i am storing all the parameters here and its working now already from 10 months so its hard to change db structure

Comment: @MikeW thanks bud i am trying this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i use the other option to sort this type of data as to decode it i need to do bit tweakings on php to and it increase the load time so i sort the data from jquery on front end.

however what i was preferring was the suggestion of @mike which is using `MID()` by this we can sort these sort of thing